# How can i solve this OSError when trying to download Kaggle datasets

Tags: kaggle, oserror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2YZa.png)

I imported opendatasets as od
dataset = 'https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata

od.download(dataset)

then it downloaded the dataset to .\tmdb-movie-metadata

Import os

data_dir = '.\tmdb-movie-metadata'

os.listdir(data_dir)

Then I start getting an OSError : The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Please help me,what can I do

Comment: What framework & language are you using?  Please [edit] your question to clarify, and also [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your question with the appropriate language & framework tags as experts typically watch specific tags to find questions to answer.   See [ask].

Comment: Also, please format your code as shown in *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*.